# vs2012 MVC4 download excel file works on desktop but not mobile "could not read the document"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using closedxml to generate an excel file on an MVC4 project using VS2012. When I test the project on VS or published on an IIS server the process works as far as I am using a desktop computer. I click the link and I get the prompt to open, save or cancel. The problem is using a mobile phone. Once I click the link, I got an error. Could not read the document. I am testing it mainly on an Iphone (5s, se, 4s, 6) and I got the same error. I use a mobile office app and if I open it there, the file shows correctly. So I am not clear how to download the file correctly on a mobile device. 
This is my code.

public FileStreamResult DownloadReport()

{

Cell cx = new Cell();

List Results = cx.GetCellDetails();

GridView GridView1 = new GridView();

GridView1.DataSource = Results;

GridView1.DataBind();

DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++) {

columns.Add(i);

dt.Columns.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text); }

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

{

dt.Rows.Add();

for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)

{

dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cells[columns[i]].Text == " " ? string.Empty : row.Cells[columns[i]].Text;

}

}

XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt,"Report");
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"test.xlsx\"");
            MemoryStream MyMemoryStream= new MemoryStream();
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(MyMemoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }

And I use razor to call it

@Html.ActionLink("Export Resuls to Excel", "DownloadReport", "Cells", new { @id="lnkExcel"})